# Data assimilation proposal

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Just a shout out regarding a [Data Assimilation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/54795/data-assimilation) site proposed on Area51. Some data assimilation questions would be on topic here, but for the most part it is a related but different discipline. Neither this site or Computational Science (or any other) has much in the way of good data assimilation questions. If you are interested, please support this proposal.

Comment: The proposal refers only to "numerical weather prediction and climate modelling." In what sense is this "data assimilation"?  What do you mean by "data assimilation" anyway, and how exactly does it differ from science, computation, librarianship, or statistics?

Comment: I mean this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_assimilation. I know it's an overly general term for a relatively specific field, but people working in the area know the meaning of the term. I should improve the description though, as the term is not very self explanatory. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It sounds like such a narrow subspecialty of statistical analysis that generating an active SE community will be difficult. Why not foster a subcommunity here, perhaps by encouraging appropriate questions, creating the necessary tags, and maybe contributing to our blog?

Comment: Data assimilation isn't a sub-specialty of statistics, it's more of an interdisciplinary field including computational science, physics and some things that could be classes broadly as statistics. It doesn't fit neatly within any existing SE site and arguably would be more at home within computational science, but still wouldn't be a great fit. I just did a shout out here as this is one place that data assimilation people might also frequent. I do agree that getting a critical mass of experts to form a site will not be easy.

Comment: I was merely paraphrasing the Wikipedia article you linked to, particularly the section prominently titled "Data assimilation as statistical estimation."